# JSON parsing for dynamic schema using DropWizard

Tags: java, json, web-services, jackson, dropwizard

I need to parse the `JSON` with dynamic schema hitting our API and I need to respond accordingly.

Dynamic schema are like,

```
{
"query": {
    <OPERATOR>: {
        <FIELD>: <VALUE>
    }
},
"fields" : [<FIELD_1>, <FIELD_2>, ...],
"from": 0,
"size": 10
}
```

OR

```
{
"query": {
    "and": [
        {
            <OPERATOR>: { 
                <FIELD>: <VALUE> 
            }
        },
        {
            <OPERATOR>: {
                    <FIELD>: <VALUE>
                }
        }
    ]
},
"fields" : [<FIELD_1>, <FIELD_2>, ...],
"from": 0,
"size": 10
}
```

our response will be based on above `JSON's`. Response will be different for each `JSON` type.
Can I use dropwizard's Jackson libraries to parse or need to write my own parser is the dilemma. If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it can be easily done but I can do that only in **GSON**

Comment: Great! In GSON, how to handle when some keys are missing? Lot of checks will make it look bad right?
So, it's writing own parser!!

Comment: @yes you are right, if you are missing the keys, than you would be able to get it's respective value. to use Gson you should have a valid JSON format

Comment: it can be array or object?? any can be possible?

Comment: Right, it can be object or array. So, I can't anticipate.

Comment: i did something like this.. you can try once tht

Answer (score 0):

if you stuck in my code then let me know because lack of time i am not refining it.

```
String result = response.toString();
    Object mainResponse = null;
    try {
        mainResponse = new JSONTokener(result).nextValue();
        if (mainResponse instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray json1 = new JSONArray(response.toString());
            Object value2 = json1.get(0);
            Object output = tryMethod((JSONObject) value2, searchString);
            outputtv.setText(output.toString());
            Log.i("Output", output.toString() + "");
        }
        if (mainResponse instanceof JSONObject) {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());
            Object output1 = tryMethod(json, searchString);
            outputtv.setText(output1.toString());
            Log.i("Output", output1 + "");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```